# Conditional selection

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run this code line in R for counting the number of patients who had a tumour relapse and also a radiotherapy, no problem:

```
> sum(datam$rt==1 & datam$recidive_chir_1==0)
[1] 9
```

When I run it in Rstudio, I get a NA.

```
\Sexpr{sum(datam$rt==1 & datam$recidive_chir_1==0)}
```

I need to enter this line code to get the right result:

```
\Sexpr{table(datam$rt==1 & datam$recidive_chir_1==0)[2]}
```

Any clue?

Comment: So in RStudio, you are running the command in a Sweave file, right?

Comment: We cant investigate without knowing what your data is. Maybe there's NA in it, maybe something in your Sweave file is doing something to it. We have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

True, I am running the command in a Sweave file.
I found the answer.
My variables rt and recidive_chir_1 are binary data. So the sum function count the number of occurence = 1 
It works.
There was most likely a problem with my data organisation

> table(datam$rt==1 & datam$recidive_chir_1==0)[2]
>   TRUE 
>     11
>
> sum(datam$rt==1 & datam$recidive_chir_1==0)
>   [1] 11

In summary, for binary variable, these two formulas are equivalent

Thanks